# How to retrieve data from a firebase database?

Tags: c#, json, firebase

I am new to Firebase databases. I need to retrieve data from the database having following structure.
[Data in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM5To.png)

I successfully retrieved data using  below code

```
var Result = await FirebaseConnection.firebaseClient.Child("SalesMaster").OrderBy("Status").EqualTo(false).OnceAsync<SalesData>();
```

but here it is not working here. Returning an error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AppliancesServer.Models.SalesDetail]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path
>   '-M3ltQ-sbTkE6bqjbp0k.SalesDetails.-M3ltQPLdUjhiEqutD3s', line 1,
>   position 177.

Used the model class as

```
public class SalesData
{

    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Mob { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string SalesNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime SalesDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
    public List<SalesDetail> SalesDetails { get; set; }

}

public class SalesDetail
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string SalesId { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProducName { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set;        
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

I appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to get the data as a JSONObject? The error itself seems clear, that you need to set the type as a JSONArray instead of a JSONObject

Comment: @Amin I used below code to retrieve data:   var Result = await FirebaseConnection.firebaseClient.Child("SalesMaster").OrderBy("Status").EqualTo(false).OnceAsync<SalesData>()